# Best practices to alias the rm command and make it safer

Tags: bash, shell, unix, script, rm

Some time ago I erroneously deleted my home folder because I ran a `rm -rf *` on the wrong terminal, whose working directory was the home folder!

I wish I had an alias for the `rm` command, but it was not the case.

Now, I am planning to make a script as an alias for `rm`.

Do you have any best practice to suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Not that I don't have sympathy, but I don't think `rm` is a dangerous command requiring an alias for safety. By using the `r` and `f` options, you're telling the shell *I know this is dangerous, and I've thought carefully about it, and it's _really_ what I want to do*. If you don't use those options, you can't delete your entire home folder with it.

Comment: Does this question cover the same information as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373156/what-is-the-safest-way-to-empty-a-directory-in-nix?

Comment: @grossvogel it happened to me once in 5+ years in which I use Linux and the terminal every day.

Comment: @puller: Sorry, I wasn't trying to say you're a bad linux user. Just that the design of `rm` is already quite good, in that it already has safety checks, and only becomes overly destructive when you disable them.

Comment: @grossvogel no offense taken :)! However, aliasing this command is a common practice. A lot of people use the -f option to avoid confirming each deletion.

Comment: Note that if you use an alias for `rm` you will get used to that alias. Then one day, you'll be on a system where the alias doesn't exist, and you'll do the wrong thing when you are least expecting it. And it probably won't be your system.

Comment: Good times if it's not your system. Assuming you can outrun them.

Comment: @puller Only on systems like RHEL that stupidly alias `rm` to `rm -i`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want a customized `rm`, don't call it `rm` but a name of yours, `myrm`, `delete` or whatever.

The `rm='rm -i'` alias is an horror because after a while using it, you will expect `rm` to prompt you by default before removing files. Of course, one day you'll run it with an account that hasn't that alias set and before you understand what's going on, it is too late.

In any case, a good way to be prepared for file loss or corruption is doing backups.

A fast alternative that will protect you against accidental file deletion or overwriting is using a file system that support unlimited snapshots like ZFS. If frequent snapshots are done automatically, you can recover the files at the state they were during the last snapshot before the incident.

Comment: i've heard that horror story personally from one of those that suffered it.

Comment: I agree but most people aren't at liberty to switch to an entirely different filesystem.

Comment: Indeed, that's the reason why I first suggest doing backups, a feature no file system forbids.

Answer (score 18):

If you want save aliases, but don't want to risk getting used to the commands working differently on your system than on others, you can to disable `rm` like this

```
alias rm='echo "rm is disabled, use remove or trash or /bin/rm instead."'
```

Then you can create your own safe alias, e.g.

```
alias remove='/bin/rm -irv'
```

or use `trash` instead.

Comment: Note that (at least in some versions) you must define the aliases in the other order.  Doing it in the order you present defines `remove` as ```echo "rm is disabled, use trash or /bin/rm instead." -irv```. And, just as a matter of common sense, wouldn't you want the message from `rm` to refer to your safe `remove` command?

Comment: You're right, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Why this answer is correct for me: it protects you against using `rm` *by mistake* (I have literally typed `rm` instead of `mv` - and more than once), but, It does not have the pitfalls of `rm -i` alias that are discussed in other answers/comments.

Answer (score 6):

You could try using [`trash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/trash.1.html) instead. Just remember to empty it once in a while...

Comment: Available with `sudo apt install trash-cli`

Answer (score 4):

Without having to change everyones profile, what you can do is place file called -i in the directory.

```
# touch -- -i
# ll
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root users  0 Jan 26 19:24 files
drwxr-xr-x 2 root users 40 Jan 26 19:24 folder_of_power
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 26 19:25 -i
-rw-r--r-- 1 root users  0 Jan 26 19:24 important
-rw-r--r-- 1 root users  0 Jan 26 19:24 very
# rm -rf *
rm: remove regular empty file `files'?
```

Comment: Won't work if the user decides to use * . * instead of just *. But still a neat trick.

Comment: afaik rm -rf . nor rm -rf .. can't succeed because you are currently in the directory.

Comment: @Peon: I believe that you mean `.* *`, rather than `* .*` (which I believe to be more common) or `* . *` (which you said). … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … For this technique to be truly, globally effective, you would need to do it in every directory where you have write permission.  But I agree, it is a neat trick.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh

trash=$HOME/tmp
mv "$@" $trash
nohup find "$trash" -type f -atime +7 -exec /bin/rm '{}' \; 2>&1 &
```

If you accidentally delete a file, recover it from the `$HOME/tmp`.

The script  moves deleted files to a `tmp` directory and deletes them next time the delete script is run if the access time is 7 days later (semi-automated cleanup of the `$HOME/tmp` directory).

Answer (score -2):

In your profile,

```
alias rm="rm -i"
```

Comment: Aliasing rm is, in my opinion, quite a poor advice and it won't help anyway in puller's case.

Comment: `rm -I` gives the best of both worlds, @jlliagre.

Comment: @Tom Wijsman, partially indeed. Changing the behavior of a critical standard Unix command is still a potential risk here. If you want it to be interactive, give the alias a different name.

Comment: @jlliagre: Hmm, so you mean scripts do catch this change?

Comment: Please read my reply http://superuser.com/a/382498/19279 to get my point.

Comment: In addition, `alias rm="rm -i"` won't change puller's case, as the resulting command would have been `rm -i -rf *` which doesn't prompt the user for deletion anyway. `alias rm=rm -I` isn't better. It will remove unconditionally all the files and directories.

Answer (score -2):

A script called `d`, with contents `mv $* /tmp`.

*edit: This is a bad idea; see below. I currently have `alias d='mv -t /tmp'` in my `.profile` instead.*

Comment: This suggestion is dangerous and could a) override already trashed files with the same name or b) delete the completely wrong files (`d "foo bar"` will delete the files `foo` and `bar`). Something safer is probably `#!/bin/bash TRASH="$( mktemp -d -t trashed.XXX )"; echo "Moving to trash $TRASH"; mv -v -- "$@" "$TRASH"` (`mktemp` and `mv` syntax depends on your system, this one works for Linux).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm fine with issue a) but issue b) is a big problem. I changed my `d` command to `alias d='mv -t /tmp'` in my `.profile`; I think that's the simple solution I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

This bash code adds the function `rm` to your `~/.bash_profile` configuration file. After running this, if you write `rm file`, you will move that file to `/tmp`

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.bash_profile
rm () {
  mv $1 /tmp
}
EOF
```

Comment: What this script/code do? Please explain so less-technical users can understand your answer.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: This does provide an answer to the question, but it's a very poor one.  Two better versions of this answer have been posted already.

Comment: This bash code adds the function `rm` to your `~/.bash_profile` configuration file. After running this file, if you write `rm file`, you will move that file to the `/tmp`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Could you please [edit] your answer to include that in the post itself?