# Is there a way to have a Y/N confirmation after Remove file/directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-terminal

I'm new to `Linux` and its terminal. 
I'm using `Ubuntu 12.04`, trying to learn about the Terminal's commands.
I learned how to remove files and directories but saw that the system never asks you if you are sure to remove or not, like showing a Y/N question, is there a way to have that (instead of using `rmdir` and `rm` and `rm -R`) ? like some command that generates a Y/N confirmation question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you type `rm -i fileA fileB fileC`, you'll get asked for confirmation for every file.

So you could define the `alias rmi=rm -i` in your shell's configuration (e.g. `~/.bashrc` for bash), and learn to type `rmi` instead of `rm`.

Some Linuxes even define `rm=rm -i`, but then [you'll start relying on this behavior whenever you enter `rm`](https://superuser.com/questions/384769/alias-rm-rm-i-considered-harmful/384770#384770).

---

You could also install [trash](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/empty-trash.1.html), which brings a "move to trash" command to your shell.