# How can I recover from mistaken 'rm *'?

Tags: unix, undo, rm

I just typed `rm *` in the wrong directory by mistake.  I had the wrong terminal window highlighted.  What are my options?

Comment: Just restore from your latest back-up - that's the whole *point* of having a back-up strategy, after all.

Comment: I have a backup, but I will lose about 3 hours of tight deadline work.

Comment: this tool has worked for me in the past: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Comment: If there was activity on the machine (writing files, particularly), the space the deleted files used to occupy is probably already recycled. Chalk it up to "Unix learning." My condolences.

Comment: @PaulR Also, I'd like to point out that Paul R's response is not helpful and does not address the question since it is obvious from context that I was not able to simply restore the work I lost from backup.  So his comment serves no purpose other than to express condescension -- and moreover, he seems to incorrectly assume that I had no backup whatsoever.  Generally speaking, I find StackExchange more useful when comments are pertinent to the question that was asked.

Comment: Now it's on SuperUser, can be closed as a dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/32355/undo-linuxs-rm?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

What you can do is re-do the three hours of work, and then think about aliasing your `rm` command to a script which works like `rm` but stages deletes through a trash bin directory which must be explicitly emptied before the files are really gone.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but aliasing `rm` isn't a great idea, since you'll get too comfortable with `rm` being a 'safe' command and if you make a mistake on another computer, it could mean real data loss. Instead alias something like `myrm` or something, that way if you run it on another computer, nothing bad will happen, and you'll have to think about using `rm` correctly. See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/382498/310285) for more detail.

Comment: @Adam So then, the opposite: alias `rm` to a command which prints "lose the habit of using rm" and exits with an error. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do as Paul -R Says, I think if i remember correctly, if write operation has occurred then its not possible to UNDELETE the item....

Maybe you can find more information here....
http://www.computerhope.com/undelete.htm