# Where did my files go after using mv command?

Tags: command-line, unix, mv

All my `.c` source files and a `Readme` file were in a subdirectory called `assignment2` in a directory called `Assignment2`. Originally, from `assignment2` directory:

```
$ ls
corrupt.c  decode.c  encode.c  fix.c  Readme
```

Then I tried to move those files from `assignment2` directory to the parent directory `Assignment2`. I typed:

```
$ mv endocode.c Assignment2 
$ ls
Assignment2  corrupt.c  decode.c  fix.c  Readme
```

```
$ mv decode.c Assignment2
$ ls 
Assignment2  corrupt.c  fix.c  Readme
```

```
$ mv corrupt.c Assignment2
$ ls
Assignment2  fix.c  Readme
```

```
$ mv fix.c Assignment2
$ mv Readme Assignment2
$ ls
Assignment2
```

Now my file originally called `Readme` is called `Assignment2` and I can't find my `.c` source files.

Where did my files go?

Comment: The **mv** command does not "move" the contents of a file (as you assumed), but rather renames that file because you did not properly specify a directory.  There is no `Assignment2` directory in the `assignment2` directory.  You would have to specify `..` (or an absolute path) to refer to the parent directory.   Except for the renamed  `Readme`, your other files have been deleted.

Comment: When moving files to a directory, **always** specify a slash at the end of the directory name: `mv -vi  endocode.c Assignment2/`  That command will fail if `Assignment2` is not a directory.

Comment: "Where did my files go?" (the title) and "how to recover them?" are two separate questions. I removed the latter because (1) it is answered [here](https://superuser.com/q/150027/432690) (it may not be the only duplicate); (2) we strongly prefer one question per question; (3) the existing answer concentrates on the title question.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, they are gone, unfortunately. The `mv` command rewrote the source with the intended destination.

As Jim said, remember to add the `/` at the end of the command, the command will fail if the target is not a directory.

However, that is still not exactly fool proof, since it relies on you remembering to add the `/` at the end of the command.

You can prevent this from happening again, by making an alias.

> Create an alias for the `mv` command

- With this solution, you'll utilize the `-b` or `--backup` arguments for the `mv` command.
- `alias mv=mv -b` will create a backup of the destination file. So in your case, you would have a bunch of backup Assignment2 files.
- `alias mv=mv --backup=numbered` this is like the command above, but gives you a bit more control on how you want the backup to be named. I've honestly never used it like this so I don't know what the output would be.
- FOR MAC USERS the `-b` flag is not supported on macOS. I don't know for the reason why. If you want to protect yourself, you have to use the `-n` flag. This tells the command to not overwrite any existing file. `alias mv=mv -n`

EXTRAS: There are other more advanced options in [How do undo MV or RM command?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-undo-mv-or-rm-command-236834/) I've never used any of the methods listed in here, besides the `-b` flag that is explained. I will try to read through them, test them and add them to the answer later on if they work correctly.

Comment: Related: [*Best practices to alias the `rm` command and make it safer*](https://superuser.com/q/382407/432690).